# error_log returning file not found in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

When I am trying to log the error from my Mysql class its saying file not found

even though the path is correct

here is the path

```
protected function sql_query($query){
        if (mysqli_query($this->conn,$query)){

                $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($this->conn);
                return $last_id;
            }
            else
                error_log(mysqli_error($this->conn) . "\n", 3, "../var/tmp/sql_error.log");
     }
```

So the folder looks like this

```
donations/api/dbHandeller.php
```

and the error log file is

```
donations/var/tmp/sql_error.log
```

**ERROR**

```
 error_log(../var/tmp/sql_error.log): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\donations\api\dbHandeler.php
```

Thanks

Comment: You should traverse back two folders. Path should be ../../var/tmp/sql_error.log

Comment: @SumitPandey okay let me try

Comment: Use an absolute path, not a relative path. `error_log(mysqli_error($this->conn) . "\n", 3, getcwd() . "/var/tmp/sql_error.log");`

Comment: @SumitPandey no it doesnot work , But according to my understanding I just need to go one level up , to donation

Comment: @Darren thanks it worked

Comment: @Vikram: oops. Better use absolute path rather than relative path.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to write to a relative path. What you want to do is write to an absolute path, using [`getcwd()`](http://php.net/getcwd).

```
error_log(mysqli_error($this->conn) . "\n", 3, getcwd() . "/var/tmp/sql_error.log");
```